# Pymongo - Process only newly updated documents?

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

So I'm new to Pymongo & MongoDB, and I'm just confused as to how best to go about this problem. I have two collections:

```
Raw_collection 
Processed_collection
```

Basically, I have raw documents that go into the `Raw_collection`, after which I process them by dropping some documents based on filters etc, and store the remaining documents into `Processed_collection`. Specifically, I plan to periodically update the records in `Raw_collection` as well.

As such, what would be the best way to process only the newly inserted documents to `Raw_collection` on a successive update? I looked into [bulk methods](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/bulk.html) but I'm not sure if that's what I want... this seems like a simple-ish problem to solve, but because of my inexperience I'm not sure what the solution would be. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: have you considered maintaining additional fields in the raw documents, like inserted timestamp and then when you update them resetting it and filtering accordingly in your processing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up doing this through pymongo's [insert_many](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_many) method has:

```
import pandas 
import pymongo

insert_raw_collection(): #call First
     result = db[collection].insert_many(documents)
     obj_id_list = result.inserted_ids
     #[ObjectId('54f113fffba522406c9cc20e'), ObjectId('54f113fffba522406c9cc20f')]
     return obj_id_list

insert_processed_collection(obj_id_list): # call Second 
     cursor = raw_collection_pandas_data_frame.find({"_id": {"$in": obid_list}})
     for doc in cursor:
         if filter(doc) == True 
             # do something
```

Basically, I return the list of inserted `ObjectId`'s from the previous insert step and perform a filtering operation so I know which I want to keep.